# How to quickly select some vectors from a given set to make the sum of them has the smallest $\ell_2$ norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, discrete-optimization

The question is how to design an effective algorithm to solve this problem:

$$
\underset{k_1,k_2,\cdots ,k_s}{\min}\lVert \sum_{i=1}^s{\mathbf{x}_{k_i}} \rVert _2,
$$

where $l (l >> s)$ is the set size, $n$ is the vector size, $ k_i $s are different numbers in $\left\{ 1,2, \cdots, l \right\}$. The set $\left\{ \mathbf{x}_i \right\} _{i=1}^{l}$ is known.

Comment: Implicitly, it seems that the $x_i$ are vectors of size $n$. Maybe better to state it clearly

Comment: $s=l$ ??????????

Comment: Sorry, $l >> s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an $n$-dimensional version of the (NP-complete) [subset sum problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), so you are unlikely to find an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much.